# Shiny bookmarking url with Scandinavian characters

Tags: r, shiny, bookmarks

As of version 0.14, Shiny supports [bookmarkable state](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html) where users can save the state of a Shiny app and get a URL which will restore the application with that state. However, bookmarking currently does not seem to support Scandinavian characters such as å, ä, or ö, when `enableBookmarking(store = "url")`. Is there anyway around this issue?